# How do I resolve the lexical ambiguity between numbers and dates in ANTLR 2?

Tags: antlr

I have two token types in my lexer defined like this:

```
NUMBERVALUE
    :    ( '0' .. '9' )+ ( '.' ( '0' .. '9' )+ )?
    ;

DATEVALUE
    :    ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' ) '-' 
         ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' ) '-' 
         ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' )
    |    ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' ) '-' 
         ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' ) '-' 
         ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' )
         ;
```

I would have thought that, since dates *must* contain a hyphen within the first five characters, then setting k=5 in the lexer options would be enough that the lexer could always tell the two apart.  However, I'm getting this warning when I run antlr:

```
warning:lexical nondeterminism between rules NUMBERVALUE and DATEVALUE upon
    k==1:'0'..'9'
    k==2:'0'..'9'
    k==3:'0'..'9'
    k==4:'0'..'9'
    k==5:'0'..'9'
```

and the parser doesn't recognise numbers with more than four digits in them.  How do I resolve the lexical ambiguity?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you run into a spurious warning due to [Linear approximate lookahead](http://www.antlr.org/doc/glossary.html#Linear_approximate_lookahead). The 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th *and* 5th character of DATEVALUE can all be digits, just not all at the same time.

I'd try to get rid of the 2/4 digit year alternative. For starters, you don't want to be responsible for the Y2.1K bug; secondly it saves you an alternative DATEVALUE syntax.
Another solution I'd try is to use a different grouping :

```
DATEVALUE
:    ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' ) (( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' ))? '-' 
     ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' ) '-' 
     ( '0' .. '9' ) ( '0' .. '9' )
     ;
```

I think it's more readable as you don't repeat the month/day part. I would put the optional part first, for readability but I understand that starting with optional parts should be avoided in these cases as it makes the parsing harder.